# Android Low level access

Tags: android

I am a new android developer...I have been developing android applications for the last 3 months. I want to have low level access to android os. By low level I mean

1. CPU controller (CPU frequency and on/off controller module)

   - Access CPU speed, Limit the cpu access to a specific process
2. Full detailed view of the running applications and their resource
   usage profile: CPU usage,memory usage, disk usage, Page faults,etc
3. Low level application profiling:CPU time, cache misses, cache hits,
   memory access,etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are trying to access CPU from you app. So I googled it a little bit. 
First of all, you need to have root access in your mobile. 
Secondly, this is the [Google's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html) to handle CPU. But increasing or decreasing CPU clock speed or anything else in low level does not necessary guaranty you that you are going to get a good result in the end instead sometimes it can kill you too. [ A gentle reminder ]

There are other great apps by which you can access some low level settings. Most of them are bit pricey but they are known  to work according to user review.

You can also modify your Kernel to give you optimum result. [Check this blog](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/adding-features-to-your-kernel)

[This blog](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html) also let you read your CPU info as well

Well. Thats all. Cheers mate.